# How can i get the current value of my range input and print in console when i am moving it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have created a range input and i want to console log the value of it every time when I move it? How can I do that ? I am unable to find what Event handler should I use?

```
            <input class="range-slide" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0">
```

This is the range input.

Comment: How about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.slider').on('input change', function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    $(this).next($('.slider_label')).html(this.value);
  });
  $('.slider_label').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
    $(this).html(value);
  });  
})
```

```css
body
        {
          font-family:sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<form>
        <p><label for="range_weight">Weight: </label> <input type="range" name="weight"  class="slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">
          <span  class="slider_label"></span></p>

        <p><label for="range_weight">Height: </label> <input type="range" name="height" class="slider" min="0" max="100" value="3">
          <span  class="slider_label"></span></p>

        <p><label for="range_weight">Length: </label> <input type="range" name="length" class="slider" min="0" max="100" value="10">
          <span  class="slider_label"></span></p>
    </form>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
```